Python - No module named 'psycopg2' even though it is installed
I have installed the psycopg2 for PSQL on OSX (Requirement already satisfied: psycopg2 in ./venv/lib/python3.12/site-packages (2.9.9)). When I run pip list, I get the following:
Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        24.0
psycopg2   2.9.9
setuptools 69.2.0
wheel      0.43.0

Python version (python -V) is Python 3.12.2.
When I run my python script, I get the following output:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/homebrew/bin/scrapy", line 8, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute())
             ^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/cmdline.py", line 160, in execute
    cmd.crawler_process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
                          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 357, in __init__
    super().__init__(settings)
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 227, in __init__
    self.spider_loader = self._get_spider_loader(settings)
                         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/crawler.py", line 221, in _get_spider_loader
    return loader_cls.from_settings(settings.frozencopy())
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 79, in from_settings
    return cls(settings)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 34, in __init__
    self._load_all_spiders()
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/spiderloader.py", line 63, in _load_all_spiders
    for module in walk_modules(name):
                  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/lib/python3.11/site-packages/scrapy/utils/misc.py", line 106, in walk_modules
    submod = import_module(fullpath)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/opt/homebrew/Cellar/python@3.11/3.11.8/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.11/lib/python3.11/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1204, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1176, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1147, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 690, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 940, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 241, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/Users/myname/pythondev/project/spiders/app.py", line 10, in <module>
    from ..db import Database as DB
  File "/Users/myname/pythondev/project/db.py", line 3, in <module>
    import psycopg2
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'psycopg2'

The python script probably cannot find psycopg2, despite it's installed. I noticed in the error output that there's a reference to a Python version 3.11, but my Python version is 3.12.
Can this be the problem? I don't see anywhere in the code any reference to version 3.11.

How did you install the package? Using pip?

I installed it as python3 -m pip install psycopg2

Try with python3.12 -m pip install psycopg2?

See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55755095/postgresql-modulenotfounderror-no-module-named-psycopg2

What eventually worked was running python3.11 -m pip install psycopg2 (I had it installed with 3.12). But I don't understand why the script is picking up Python3.11, because it should be used Python3.12
